# Since Mormonism allows for humans to become gods in the afterlife, does this mean it is polytheistic?

Tags: lds, polytheism

It is stated that Mormons believe in an afterlife scenario that includes the ability to become a god of their own planet (only men though).  Does this mean Mormonism is polytheistic?  Would this be the only example of polytheistic Christianity?

Comment: And aside, becoming "a god of their own planet (only men though)" is all wrong. Where have you been doing your research? Do you have a valid LDS citation for that?

Comment: I was speaking to an ex-mormon form Utah but perhaps I mischaracterized it or misunderstood.

Comment: That makes sense, since most active Latter-day Saints would probably be startled by the idea of "getting your own planet" and only the men having that option. I think the topic you're looking for is [exaltation](http://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-47-exaltation?lang=eng). Hope that helps.

Comment: @Matt I think my ex-mormon peer was so startled by the entire thing, that he decided to leave.

Comment: This partly explains the confusion:

"Each one of you has it within the realm of his possibility to develop a kingdom over which you will preside as its king and god. You will need to develop yourself and grow in ability and power and worthiness, to govern such a world with all of its people." 
(“. . . the Matter of Marriage” [address delivered at University of Utah Institute of Religion, 22 Oct. 1976], 2).

Comment: "Then will they become Gods...they will never cease to increase and to multiply, worlds without end. When they receive their crowns, their dominions, they then will be prepared to frame earths like unto ours and to people them in the same manner as we have been brought forth by our parents, by our Father and God” Brigham Young, Journal of Discourses 17:143

Comment: add those to the Question. but one thing to remember is that just because it was written doesn't mean it should be taken completely literally, even in the bible literary devices were used to show an idea and were not meant to be taken literally.

Comment: However there are clearly Mormons who take it literally.  Your concern then begs, how do you know what is literal and what isn't?  As atheist, I take the position that most theists can't tell the difference.